# Why vba subroutine terminates in the middle of processing couple of thousands of records?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on processing and formatting couple of thousands of rows on an excel sheet and copy the formatted line on another sheet.

Vba terminates in the middle of the "for" loop. The code is simple

```
 ...
 for i=1 to rowNum 'rowNum is 5633 in this sample
   Sheets("Source").Activate
   If IsEmpty(Sheets("Source").Cells(i,1)) Then
        GoTo NextIteration
   End If
   'read row information  
   Sheets("Destination").Activate
   'Based on the conditions, paste data into cells 
NextIteration:
Next i
....
```

For some reason, I think excel runs out of memory! But I have no proof! 
I'd appreciate if anyone can help me solving this issue!

Comment: Are you running option explicit, and what have you declared (e.g., Dim i as Long)?

Comment: "I think Excel runs out of memory" what makes you say that? How do you know it's "terminating"? Are you getting an error message? Usually code that abruptly termniates is rather loud & clear about it. Are you sure your code isn't just terribly inefficient and runs faster than Excel can refresh/keep up, so it whites-out and says "(not responding)"? If that's the case, read up on avoiding `Select` and `Activate`, and about toggling `Application.Calculation` mode, `Application.EnableEvents`, and `Application.ScreenUpdating`.

Comment: @Cyril yes, i is Long

Comment: There are many things inefficient in your code: you have `Sheets("Source").Activate` inside the loop. You can just activate the sheet outside the loop once and I guess you don't even need to activate any sheet. You have used `IsEmpty` function to evaluate whether the cell is blank or not. You need to use cells(x,y).value` to make sure the function is returning a good response, however, I would evaluate the cell value simply with `cells(x,y) =""` `IsEmpty` is really designed to make sure a object has been defined or a class instance has been instantiated.

Comment: There is no need to use `Sheets("Destination").Activate` inside your loop. VBA will copy paste without a sheet being activated.

Comment: "The code is simple" - it's not really *that* simple: you seem to have left quite a lot out...

Comment: If you don't get an error message and it just says 'not responding' then it's just taking a long time to run due to inefficient code. Stop using .activate will help.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for your comments. I found the issue! I have a column that supposed to contain numeric values, there was a type mismatch on one of the rows but vba wasn't showing me the mismatch error! instead, it was terminating. I added another check for reading numeric values and now it works!

Comment: @Carol you are right I removed the "Activate"

Comment: Is your code part of a UDF?  That's the only reason I can think of for code to "terminate" without displaying an error message.